# C# Winforms - Replace a substring

Tags: c#, string

How do I replace a substring with another string ?

```
string line = "ABC00.00GHIABCDEFGH00.00IJKLM00.00NO";
```

I would like to replace the second instance of 00.00 with 12.34.

Comment: And what did you try? How winforms is correlated to problem?

Comment: @jonathana he wants to replace only the **second** instance of `00.00`.  That would replace every instance.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to use a combination of `IndexOf` and `SubString`:

```
var line = "ABC00.00GHIABCDEFGH00.00IJKLM00.00NO";
var indexOfSecondOccurance = line.IndexOf("00.00", line.IndexOf("00.00")+1);
var result = line.Substring(0, indexOfSecondOccurance) + "12.34" + line.Substring(indexOfSecondOccurance + 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0;
string line2 = Regex.Replace(line, "00\.00", m => ++x == 2 ? "12.34" : m.Value);
```

The code works as follows:

1. Regex searches for every instance of "00.00".
2. As soon as it finds string being searched, it calls up MatchEvalutor delegate which passes Match object to the function.
3. Because we need only second instance, we must track the occurrence of match. The lambda function is using `x` variable for that case.
4. Then the simplest thing: first, we increment `x`, then compare it to `2`. If x equals 2, then we return "12.34", otherwise we return what we found.

Comment: An explanation to the piece of code would be useful, especially in the case of regular expressions. Not everyone is familiar/comfortable with them and the code on its own is not especially helpful to the poster.

Comment: I think the pattern should be "00\.00". Otherwise the special meaning of the dot is used, that is it will match any character.

Comment: @Mike Oops! But this is the moment when `.` matched `.` :) Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Split` and `Join`:

```
var line = "ABC00.00GHIABCDEFGH00.00IJKLM00.00NO";
var parts = line.Split(new [] { "00.00" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var line2 = String.Join("00.00", parts.Take(2)) + String.Join("00.00", parts.Skip(2));
```

Here, we split on `00.00`, thus removing each instance from the split array.  Then we recombine the string back together, but we skip the undesired instance of `00.00`.

Comment: OP wanted to replace the second instance instead of remove it so line2 should be assigned String.Join("00.00", parts.Take(2)) + "12.34" + String.Join("00.00", parts.Skip(2)); Correct?